# Sum of all shortest paths queries

Tags: graph, tree, shortest-path

I need help with this problem.

We have that `D(G,u,v)` is number of edges on shortest path from `u` to `v` in graph `G`.

We are given a tree `T` with `N` vertices and `Q` queries of following type:

If we add edge `(a,b)` to tree `T`, obtaining graph `G1`, then what is the value of `sum(1 <=u < v <= N) D(G1,u,v)`

Queries are independent

```
1<=N<=260000

1<=Q<=200000

D(T,a,b)<=16
```

For each query I called BFS from every node and calculated sum of distances, but my algorithm was to slow. Can someone give me more efficient approach?

Comment: Is (u, v) remain the same pair of nodes across queries?